# "no such symbol C_contour" error when loading package "foreign" in R

Tags: r

I want to use the package `foreign` to turn an Octave text file representing a read audio file into R vector data; however, when I try to load the package using `library(foreign)`, I get the following error message:

```
Loading required package: Matrix
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Matrix’ in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
no such symbol C_contour in package /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/graphics/libs/graphics.so 
Error: package ‘Matrix’ could not be loaded
```

I tried deleting the R.framework file and reinstalling (a method which worked for someone else with a similar error) and continued to encounter this error.
Does anyone know what the holdup here is?